# jQuery & Facebook C# SDK in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 website, on the _Layout.cshtml page, I am creating a jQuery AJAX request to an action method that has "CanvasAttribute" trying to retrieve user details.

The response of that ajax request is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            top.location = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?scope=user_about_me&state=eyJyIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hcHBzLmZhY2Vib29rLmNvbS9jY3RfdmJjX3NtL0hvbWUvUHJvZmlsZSJ9&client_id=...&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44302/facebookredirect.axd";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

I thought that authentication with FB only takes place the first time an action method is called and that is designated with the "CanvasAttribute". It seems that on every request the authentication is taking place.

Any solution?

Comment: are you sure you are passing the signed_request during ajax request, coz if CanvasAuthorizer doesn't find it, it assumes the user has not authorized your app, thus asks for permission. but since the user already authorized ur app, he/she will not see the allow/don't allow button.